# Compilation Errors / DNX Multiple References / Nuget Lock File Errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, dnx

On a machine where an *older* version of this code works just fine, pulling a fresh version of the same project out of source control, running nuget package restore (which writes the `project.lock.json` files), then trying to build outputs errors like this:

```
Error   CS1703  
Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 
'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\Facades\System.Runtime.dll' and 
'C:\Users\[username]\.dnx\packages\System.Runtime\4.0.0\ref\dotnet\System.Runtime.dll'. 
Remove one of the duplicate references.
```

I understand what it's trying to tell me, `System.Runtime.dll` was imported twice.  What I don't understand is how to get Visual Studio 2015 to fix it.

The only difference I can find in the project is in the `project.lock.json` file.  Comparing the working project to the non-working project shows results like this.  The working file is on the LEFT:

[image: comparison of project.lock.json]

So, from what I understand, the incorrect lock file on the right is telling NuGet to attempt to use the new .NET Core stuff while the one on the left is saying "Use .NET Framework 4.5"?

The project is using "ASP.NET 5 RC1 Update 1".  I am confused about this too, ASP.NET 5 should be using the new .NEt Core stuff and not "Framework 4.5"?  If that's the case then the "incorrect" lock file seems correct to me since it targets "ref/dotnet"?

Copying the working `project.lock.json` file over the non working one allows the project to build, but this is not a *solution* to the problem in my book.  What is it about this project or machine environment that is causing this to happen?  Something, somewhere, needs to be uninstalled?  Installed?  Changed?

Edit to include project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "Model Class Library",
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": { }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "System.ComponentModel.Annotations": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Delete your project.lock.json file.
- In a cmd prompt or powershell window, run `dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-final`
- In the same powershell window, navigate to the root of the project and run `dnu restore`

I suspect that the working project.lock.json file was built against a different runtime version than 1.0.0-rc1-update1.

Comment: I had/used `1.0.0-rc1-update1` instead of `1.0.0-rc1-final`.  It "worked" in that it rebuilt the lock files, but the end result was the same as if Visual Studio had done it on its own.  I think this project was created *before* ASP.NET 5 and then upgraded....so that's why it seems to want the older references in the lock file.

Comment: @FirstDivision understood. In that case, maybe you should share your project.json.

Comment: I added the project json for one of the projects.  It's a very simple one that only contains shared model classes for the rest of the project.